# How to invoke a function(like playing a an audio which says "STOP") when the stopwatch passes over a minute in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

var app = angular.module('fruitjs.timer', []);
app.controller('timerController', [ '$scope', '$interval', function($scope, $interval) {
    var interval, incrementTimer, actions;
    actions = { start: "Start", stop: "Stop" };

```
$scope.timer = 0;
$scope.action = actions.start;

incrementTimer = function() {
    $scope.timer += 1;
};

$scope.toggle = function() {
    if ($scope.action === actions.start) {
        $scope.action = actions.stop;
        interval = $interval(incrementTimer, 1000);

    } else if ($scope.action === actions.stop) {
        $scope.action = actions.start;
        $interval.cancel(interval);
    }
};

$scope.reset = function () {
    $interval.cancel(interval);
    $scope.timer = 0;
    $scope.action = actions.start;
};
```

}]);

Comment: Please provide, at minimum, the stopwatch module in question, and the progress you've made attempting to accomplish this task. As is, your question is too broad and requires too much of the community to help you.

Comment: @mikelawson done sir.